# freeze_time `ignore` doesn't seem to work in more complicated setup (Django + S3 / boto)

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, python-import, freezegun

I am using Django with S3 as the file storage (which uses boto3/botocore libs). I have a "management" command which creates some Django instances - **I use freezegun, so these instances appear to be created in the past**. However some of these models contain files, that are being saved to S3 - which raises some exceptions:

```
...
  File "/home/rado/.virtualenvs/twisto/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/rado/.virtualenvs/twisto/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (RequestTimeTooSkewed) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The difference between the request time and the current time is too large.
```

this is due to some authentication code in `botocore.auth` module, that checks for time differences. I tried to solve this issue using `ignore` parameter (`freeze_time(datetime_in_past, ignore=['botocore'])`), but it didn't help, `botocore.auth` still used the `FakeDatetime` (I used debugger with breakpoints to pinpoint the issue).

I tried to recreate the issue with a simple reproducible example, so I came up with following:

```py
# test.py
from freezegun import freeze_time
from datetime import datetime
import stuff_in_between

import test_time #  <-- note this unused import

with freeze_time(datetime(2019, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), ignore=['test_time']):
    print(f'frozen time: {datetime.now()}')
    stuff_in_between.call_test_time()
```

```py
# stuff_in_between.py
def call_test_time():
    import test_time
    test_time.test_time()
```

```py
# test_time.py
from datetime import datetime

def test_time():
    print(f'real datetime.now: {datetime.now()}')
```

This code correctly works, freeze_time ignore `test_time` and it prints `real datetime.now: <real time>`. However if I omit the marked unused import in `test.py`, it doesn't work - freeze_time doesn't `ignore` the module and the script prints out `real datetime.now: <fake time>`.

I thought I could try out something similar in my real Django go, so I did following:

```py
...
import botocore
import botocore.auth
# hell, try to import everything possible related to S3
with freeze_time(datetime_in_past, ignore=['botocore']:
   ...
   # create some instances, that also save files to S3
```

This hasn't worked no matter what I imported or ignored, `botocore.auth` still continued to use `FakeDatetime`...
Is there a bug in `freezegun`? Or am I misusing the library in some way? Why does it behave like this?

**Just to clarify** - I don't care about the files being set with time offset. They are just fine to be set with real time in S3. I only care about the models being saved with frozen time. So if I had following model:

```py
class Image(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file = models.ImageField(...)
```

field `date_created` would use the frozen time.

Comment: From your description it's not clear to me what you're using freezegun for in this context. I suspect freezegun isn't the right tool for this job, but as mentioned it's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Are you trying to create objects with a timestamp in the past in S3?

Comment: @Dunedan I've added a clarification - I only want the models themselves - and the datetime fields they contain - to be saved with fake time.

Comment: Why don't you simply use the `default` parameter for the `DateTimeField` to set a static time, instead of using freezegun. That could look like `date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1))`